# How to process the following query

Tags: java, jpa

how to process the follwing query getting result list will return array list of unknown type. do i have to create dto and select to new of this object.

```
SELECT c.currency, SUM(c.population)
FROM Country c
WHERE 'Europe' MEMBER OF c.continents
GROUP BY c.currency
```

Comment: Create class containing variable currency and population.List will contain tht class

Comment: is there a different way without creating dto

Comment: multi selection? http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select#SELECT_in_Criteria_Queries_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `Class` containing attribute currency and population and then the sql result will be `list` of the class.

or

Create `MultiValueMap` which will contain key as currency and value as population so sql result will be list of `MultiValueMap`

Answer (score 1):

Create a pojo with a constructor having the two parameters currency (probably String) and populationSize (as java.Lang.Number) and call the populaionSize.longValue() to get the number.

```
public ClassConstructor(String currency, Number populationSize)
{
    this.currency = currency;
    this.pop size = populationSize.longValue();
}
```

Note:  You should probably check the size of the populationSize to not hit the long boundary.

Change your query to

```
em.query("SELECT new " + YourClass.class.getName() + "(...,...) from ...");
```

and retrieve the result as list.

Note: If you can define a dto type (TypedQuery) you don't have to cast the List later.

Comment: Not sure if a boundary check is really required. Max long is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, whereas global population is currently around 7,211,186,380. I think you've got a while yet ;)

Comment: The reason for the Number is that based on the db type, it can be int, long or even biginteger.